# Can I raise the Resolution/DPI of a Windows Form? (some means to scale up controls?)

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, resolution, dpi

I am developing a Windows Forms application in C# for use in an office. Thus far, with Anchoring and Autosizing, the controls lay themselves out well at the default form size, when maximized, etc.

The form does not look good in a conference room, on a large projected screen. Text is too small to be read easily.

We run Windows 7 on our machines, so as an experiment I raised the Display rendering from 100% to 150%. This made the text on the controls blurry, so I did some research and then added this to my Main() method.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware;
```

This worked really well - the app scaled up, the controls were large and readable, and everything continued to lay out well. The only problem is that changing the Display rendering forces you to log out, it inconvenient, and realistically our users will never do it. The computers are likely to stay at 100%.

Can I do this from within the application? I've seen a lot of questions about forcing an app down to 96 DPI, but is it possible to force it UP to 120 or 144 DPI?

Or maybe there is a different and better means to achieve the same goal? I would like to avoid building a separate "Presentation Mode" interface with large fonts if at all possible.

Comment: I think you're looking for WPF instead of winforms, which is resolution independent by default. All your problems can be resolved in WPF by wrapping the entire application in a `Viewbox` (2 lines of XAML).

Comment: @HighCore Unfortunately, this application is supposed to be a companion to other applications we use internally, and since those were done in winforms, we have to continue to use winforms.

Comment: @HighCore I've found I can get something close to my desired effect by running the following:  
`this.SuspendLayout();`  
`this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(72F, 72F);`  
`this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));`  
`this.PerformAutoScale();`

Comment: regardless if you already have existing (legacy) winforms apps, winforms is not recommended for any new projects. It is a really old technology that is not up to today's UI standards. It doesn't really matter if it's a "companion" to other applications, WPF is the default and preferred UI framework for .Net Windows Desktop applications.

Comment: I know this is a bad excuse - but many of our developers who would maintain this application going forward are not versed in WPF. What's that? It's different? We don't like that! 
I routinely find myself reminding people that things like Ribbon toolbars have been common since oh, 2007? Not everything can stay looking like it's out of Windows XP. But I meet much resistance with that.

Comment: sorry, fire all your staff and get decent developers. No offense, but resisting XAML-based technologies in favor of winforms is equivalent to resisting .Net in favor of VB6. *objects? classes? inheritance? LINQ? what's that? we don't like that!* - See my point?

Comment: BTW, you might want to show your winforms developers [this little clip](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) and then tell them to try to do the same in winforms...

Comment: Wait, you're letting your developers decide your architecture? Because they don't want to bother learning new things? I think I'll have to agree with HC on this one.

Comment: I hear ya. Currently I'm the low man on the totem pole. We'll address the issue of continuous learning and use of modern, secure technology soon enough. Maybe not this application, or the next one, but it's definitely on the radar.

Comment: My company has strong ties to the industrial sector, where on the factory floor it is very common to use the same technology for 10 or 20 years (Ethernet? No, use RS232 serial buses. New machines? No, this PLC from the 80s works great). There's actually a lot of revenue to be made in being an expert in old stuff, and not always swapping out to something new. I know that doesn't apply to our expertese, but the way of thinking is prevalent among many here, which is something I'm working to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the effort that would go into properly working with DPI in Windows Forms, we ended up pursuing a much easier route: changing the fonts of the form.

If all of the controls are set to AutoScale by Font (which is their default), you can override the system font on a per-form basis.

```
this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Some controls don't pull from the form's font, and would have to be set individually, such as menustrips.

```
menuStrip1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

We changed font size for the form to 14 and for the menus to 15 to increase readability, and changed them back to their original values to return to standard mode.

Note that just as some controls will ignore the form font by default, many (if not all) controls can and will ignore this if you manually configure their font (such as making text bold, or italics, etc.). Every instance of this needs to be handled individually.